# how do you append a word to every line that starts with the word kernel?

Tags: shell-script

I have a file with many lines.   I want to append the word audit=1 to the end of every line that starts with the word kernel.
Here is an example:

```
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-LOTS OF INFO.......M rd_NO_DM
```

should look like

```
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-LOTS OF INFO.......M rd_NO_DM audit=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/^kernel.*/& audit=1' filename
```

If you want to write the results to the same file, `sed -i 's/...`

Comment: alternately, `sed '/^kernel/ s/$/ audit=1/' file`

Answer (score 0):

With awk, you could use

```
awk '$1 == "kernel" {$NF = $NF OFS "audit=1"} 1' file
```

or

```
awk '$1 == "kernel" {$(++NF) = "audit=1"} 1' file
```

Comment: Note that it affects the spacing in that line. You may prefer `$0 = $0 " audit=1"`

Comment: ... or `/^kernel/ { print $0, "audit=1"; next } 1`.